# What will happen when iOS has upgraded?

Tags: iphone

I am a test Engineer. I am testing one application.

I am not doing any compatibility testing.

If iOS upgraded to 4.3.2 to 5 what will happen for my app?

Will it work or dev team has to release another build?

Regards,
Chandra

Comment: It will not work. Please step back from the iPhone slowly while a team of trained professionals handles the issue

Comment: The app will still run, it doesn't need to be rebuilt, but as a tester you really ought to actually try it and make sure everything still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not straight answer for your question. It all depends on the app.

If there are any methods used that will not work any more on iOS 5 it could make the app crash.

Just be sure to install the iOS 5 SDk en test the app in simulator to see what happens. There is on minor thing to keep in mind. Apps build with iOS sdk prior to 5 will be allowed to for instance change to look and feel op UI element via the drawRect something that app build with iOS 5 can't do on iOS 5.

My experience is that the apps running fine on iOS 4.3 will do fine on 5, but compiling apps with the 5.0 SDK could make them break.